# Run a code after specific time in php

Tags: php

I need to run a code again and again on server after a fixed time. Is it possible to do so?

I am using PHP.

Comment: They're called cron jobs. I'm not going to bother explaining them because there are millions of pages on Google that do that already.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/984622/what-options-are-there-for-executing-a-php-script-at-a-certain-time-every-day , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981036/php-script-to-execute-at-certain-times , etc.

Answer (score 4):

You can create scheduled tasks through [CronJobs.](http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml)

Also have a look through this article to run PHP scripts through [Cron.](http://www.htmlcenter.com/blog/running-php-scripts-with-cron/)

So basically what you will have to do is **create the script** you want to run via PHP and using the above articles **create a Cron** for the specific interval.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Cron job](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to call a PHP script at certain intervals.

Comment: can i do this

function doSomething()
{
//do 
sleep(3600)
doSomething()
}

Comment: @Praveen Yes, but your script will hang for that amount of time. Not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is called [Cron](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/introducing-cron)

From the Article

> Cron is very simply a Linux module
>   that allows you to run commands at
>   predetermined times or intervals. In
>   Windows, it’s called Scheduled Tasks.
>   The name Cron is in fact derived from
>   the same word from which we get the
>   word chronology, which means order of
>   time.

Answer (score 0):

Please use Cron job to accomplish the task.
You may execute php cli to start the PHP engine in command-line mode.
You can modify a setting text file to instruct Cron job when to execute.

Answer (score 0):

In your hosting control panel you should have an option to set a Cron Job that can be used to run a PHP script at any interval. The command you need to use should look like this:

`/usr/bin/php -q /home/USERNAME/public_html/PathToFile`

The cron setup will allow you to setup how often your script will run, every minute, 5 mins, hour, daily, weekly, etc.