# how to execute some function on specific time implicitly

Tags: php

Can anyone help 
I need to run a php file or function on a specific time (atmost predifined).
So i can not find any way to do this , i think about server variable.
This has to be done without browser i mean there is no chance that browser run at that time it may be or may not. I hope you understand the problem pls give solution Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP script to execute at certain times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981036/php-script-to-execute-at-certain-times)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use cron (on *nix) or scheduled tasks (windows)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Most web host software (such as cPanel) allows you to edit the crontab (the list of scheduled tasks) via the web interface

Answer (score 0):

they are called cron jobs

[Run a code after specific time in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816409/run-a-code-after-specific-time-in-php)