# Scheduling execution of a function

Tags: php, cakephp

How can I get a function executed in a php (cakephp) application at a specific point of time, without the intervention of a person clicking the link or triggering the function by himself/herself?

Comment: Use cron or whatever OS scheduling tool you have available.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to execute some function on specific time implicitly.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220561/how-to-execute-some-function-on-specific-time-implicitly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All other answers so far are right, you'll need to schedule a cron job (or scheduled task on Windows). With that said, CakePHP is designed to answer HTTP requests and not work through the command line.

For a tutorial specific to CakePHP, visit http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/mathew_attlee/2006/12/05/calling-controller-actions-from-cron-and-the-command-line.

Comment: Your answer is partially correct. Cake has a pretty robust console system. Look at http://book.cakephp.org/view/110/Creating-Shells-Tasks and http://book.cakephp.org/view/846/Running-Shells-as-cronjobs

Comment: @William - Thanks! I had no idea we could do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Linux or Mac, try Cron:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cron

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

For Linux:

> https://www.interspire.com/support/kb/questions/298/How+do+I+set+up+CRON+on+my+server%3F

For Windows:

> http://troy.jdmz.net/cron/

There is one more stuff, the above method are done on your server machine, but if you are expecting to do this from a page (browser), then you have to use [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp) + [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) you can get it done.

Answer (score 0):

Yes using CRON as the scheduler and then using cakePHP shells to execute the code you need.

Here's the documentation from cakePHP 2.0:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html