# How can i add exception?

Tags: php

I have a  php site **www.test.com.**

In the index page of this site ,i am updating another site's(www.pgh.com) database by  the following php code.

```
$url = "https://pgh.com/test.php?userID=".$userName. "&password=" .$password ;
$response = file_get_contents($url);
```

But,now the site `www.pgh.com` is down.So it also affecting my site  'www.test.com'.

So how can i add some exception or something else to this code,so that my site should work if other site is down

Answer (score 3):

```
$response = file_get_contents($url);
if(!$response)
{
    //Return error
}
```

From the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php#82527)
Adding a timeout:

```
$ctx = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'timeout' => 1
        )
    )
);
file_get_contents("http://example.com/", 0, $ctx);
```

[file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) returns false on fail.

Comment: This will take ages to time out if the remote host is unreachable.

Comment: @Wrikken even a minimal timeout of a second is going to delay page delivery by that amount of time, for every request during the outage. Caching is the only good way to go here.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

- Add a timeout to the `file_get_contents` call using [`stream_get_context()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) (The manual has good examples; Docs for the `timeout` parameter [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php)). This is not perfect, as even a one second's timeout will cause a notable pause when loading the page.
- More complex but better: Use a caching mechanism. Do the `file_get_contents` request in a separate script that gets called frequently (e.g. every 15 minutes) using a [cron job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984622/what-options-are-there-for-executing-a-php-script-at-a-certain-time-every-day) (if you have access to one). Write the result to a local file, which your actual script will read.