# What are possible source of errors when getting json fom a website to be sent to server?

Tags: php, json, twitter

I am facing problems in sending json response to php that I get from twitter. I had spent a lot of time but I could not figure out source of error. **The console is outputting no error but my jquery code to POST json is going to failure block.** I validated json from lintjson & its valid. Can someone kindly tell what could be error causing things when sending json that is received from a web source like Twitter in this case. That may be helped me narrow down my problem finding.

```
  <html>
  <?php
  function searchResults($q) {

      $host = "http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=" . urlencode( $q ) . "&rpp=100";
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

    //Raw xml
      $result = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      $xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
      return json_encode($xml);
      } 
    ?>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js">
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>//curl sends valuse, I test it by a test php block here
    <script type="text/javascript"> var msg_top = <?php echo   
    searchResults('windows');?>;
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
       $.ajax({
       url: "script.php",
       type: "POST",
       dataType: "json",
       data: msg_top,
       success: function(){
       alert("success");
       }
      });
    alert("failure");
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

this is json response from twitter

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> var test_json = {\"id\":\"tag:search.twitter.com,2005:search\\/#DIYSe_F\",\"link\":[{\"@attributes\":{\"type\":\"text\\/html\",\"href\":\"http:\\/\\/search.twitter.com\\/search?q=%23DIYSe_F\",\"rel\":\"alternate\"}},{\"@attributes\":{\"type\":\"application\\/atom+xml\",\"href\":\"http:\\/\\/search.twitter.com\\/search.atom?q=%23DIYSe_F&rpp=100\",\"rel\":\"self\"}},{\"@attributes\":{\"type\":\"application\\/opensearchdescription+xml\",\"href\":\"http:\\/\\/search.twitter.com\\/opensearch.xml\",\"rel\":\"search\"}},{\"@attributes\":{\"type\":\"application\\/atom+xml\",\"href\":\"http:\\/\\/search.twitter.com\\/search.atom?q=%23DIYSe_F&rpp=100&since_id=7750301532557312\",\"rel\":\"refresh\"}}],\"title\":\"#DIYSe_F - Twitter Search\",\"updated\":\"2010-11-24T22:20:44Z\",\"entry\":[{\"id\":\"tag:search.twitter.com,2005:7559269595488256\",\"published\":\"2010-11-24T22:20:44Z\",\"link\":[{\"@attributes\":{\"type\":\"text\\/html\",\"href\":\"http:\\/\\/twitter.com\\/_smir\\/statuses\\/7559269595488256\",\"rel\":\"alternate\"}},{\"@attributes\":{\"type\":\"image\\/png\",\"href\":\"http:\\/\\/s.twimg.com\\/a\\/1289849896\\/images\\/default_profile_5_normal.png\",\"rel\":
        \":\"image\"}}],\"title\":\"#DIYse_F HIE_STRUCT: HIERARCHICAL STRUCTURE: hierarchical structure to display \\nmessages of Functions and Qualities types\",\"content\":\"<a href=\\\"http:\\/\\/search.twitter.com\\/search?q=%23DIYse_F\\\" onclick=\\\"pageTracker._setCustomVar(2, \'result_type\', \'recent\', 3);pageTracker._trackPageview(\'\\/intra\\/hashtag\\/#DIYse_F\');\\\"><b>#DIYse_F<\\/b><\\/a> HIE_STRUCT: HIERARCHICAL STRUCTURE: hierarchical structure to display \\nmessages of Functions and Qualities types\",\"updated\":\"2010-11-24T22:20:44Z\",\"author\":{\"name\":\"_smir (Smeer)\",\"uri\":\"http:\\/\\/twitter.com\\/_smir\"}},{\"id\":\"tag:search.twitter.com,2005:7552659368189952\",\"published\":\"2010-11-24T21:54:28Z\",\"link\":[{\"@attributes\":{\"type\":\"text\\/html\",\"href\":\"http:\\/\\/twitter.com\\/_smir\\/statuses\\/7552659368189952\",\"rel\":\"alternate\"}},{\"@attributes\":{\"type\":\"image\\/png\",\"href\":\"http:\\/\\/s.twimg.com\\/a\\/1289849896\\/images\\/default_profile_5_normal.png\",\"rel\":\"image\"}}],\"title\":\"#DIYse_F SEND_MSG: users can send messages of four types i.e.  \\n\\nFunction,Quality,Solution, and delivery\",\"content\":\"<a href=\\\"http:\\/\\/search.twitter.com\\/search?q=%23DIYse_F\\\" onclick=\\\"pageTracker._setCustomVar(2, \'result_type\', \'recent\', 3);pageTracker._trackPageview(\'\\/intra
\\/hashtag\\/#DIYse_F\');\\\"><b>#DIYse_F<\\/b><\\/a> SEND_MSG: users can send messages of four types i.e.  \\n\\nFunction,Quality,Solution, and delivery\",\"updated\":\"2010-11-24T21:54:28Z\",\"author\":{\"name\":\"_smir (Smeer)\",\"uri\":\"http:\\/\\/twitter.com\\/_smir\"}},{\"id\":\"tag:search.twitter.com,2005:7548895705956352\",\"published\":\"2010-11-24T21:39:31Z\",\"link\":[{\"@attributes\":{\"type\":\"text\\/html\",\"href\":\"http:\\/\\/twitter.com\\/Babar_Shahzad\\/statuses\\/7548895705956352\",\"rel\":\"alternate\"}},{\"@attributes\":{\"type\":\"image\\/png\",\"href\":\"http:\\/\\/a1.twimg.com\\/profile_images\\/1090185625\\/29465_391454998679_533808679_3864564_6071800_n_normal.jpg\",\"rel\":\"image\"}}],\"title\":\"#DIYse_F READ_MSG: Users can read messages of all four types in  \\n\\ndifferent windows\",\"content\":\"<a href=\\\"http:\\/\\/search.twitter.com\\/search?q=%23DIYse_F\\\" onclick=\\\"pageTracker._setCustomVar(2, \'result_type\', \'recent\', 3);pageTracker._trackPageview(\'\\/intra\\/hashtag\\/#DIYse_F\');\\\"><b>#DIYse_F<\\/b><\\/a> READ_MSG: Users can read messages of all four types in  \\n\\ndifferent windows\",\"updated\":\"2010-11-24T21:39:31Z\",\"author\":{\"name\":\"Babar_Shahzad (Babar Shahzad Ch)\",\"uri\":\"http:\\/\\/twitter.com\\/Babar_Shahzad\"}}]};
```

Comment: Isn't this a JSONP request? You should use `jsonp` as data type

Comment: @Pekka, which one? If you are asking the json then I copied it from console, console replaces php to js assignment statement with this. Actually when it showed an error on that i.e. 'missing ;' then it replaced it with this when highlighting error. I copied it from there.

Comment: @XCeptable this is not a JSON response, it's JSONP, so it contains `<script>` tags that will break the JSON variable. However, I'm not sure what you are doing here in the first place. Why fetch something using PHP in one page, only to send it back to the server? Why the detour through the client's machine?

Comment: @Pekka, yes, this is response from twitter server to this function.I am not an experienced web developer.I have to store the tweets into database for some manipulation that are returned using this function. Before I was direct printing them to web page.So for saving,I thought this way that on pageload, all fetched tweets i.e. xml obejct are sent to database through ajax.I have no specifically described server, some functions are working on this main page, some are handled by other pages on back.If there is some other good approach, you can tell me.

Comment: @XCeptable you can do fetch the tweets directly in script.php or process them in the code above, no need to take the Ajax detour.

Comment: @Pekka, yes I know that could be done as I did that to test if something is going to script as I was not able to check that since I come to know about var_dump. So, you mean just from xml object, fetch all data normally by loop in script.php & insert that into table OR if you have some other idea

Comment: @Xceptable yup, that sounds about right.

Comment: @Pekka, one question is I need to keep table updated, by using ajax the idea was it load most recent tweets & that are inserted. How do I do that for that script as all control lies in this page. How & when that will be invoked so that that is updated.

Comment: @XCeptable you can keep the Ajax approach but do all the processing in script.php then

Comment: @Pekka, but again ajax will start when that page is invoked. How you would have dealt with same thing ? I mean this whole scenario ...

Comment: @XCeptable if you want this to happen frequently without having to invoke a page, you need a cron job: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: @Pekka, does php support some implementation of Cron like OR liking technology that I could use on script. I am asking all these questions as your very nice suggestion seem to me workable for me, I mean I could do.

Comment: @XCeptable a real cron job would be preferable. There is "poor man's cron" that might work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/984622/what-options-are-there-for-executing-a-php-script-at-a-certain-time-every-day

Comment: @Pekka, you say you can keep ajax approach but do all processing in script.php. If cron is used, I think ajax is not need.just simple fetch all values from searchFunction & insert into table.Would you comment on it.

Comment: @XCeptable yes, if you use cron, you won't need the Ajax part

Comment: @Pekka, OK, thank you for the help, I start work that way :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many potential sources of errors to name them all; the right way to fix them is step-by-step debugging of the code, and watching the error console of the browser.

Show some code - I'm sure somebody people will come up with good approaches.

Comment: I would say that the right way is to write unit tests, so that your time watching the debugger isn't wasted the next time you change the code!

Comment: @Arafangion that's a commendable idea. Why don't you elaborate a bit on how to implement unit testing in this scenario?

Comment: I'd separate each part of the problem into layers - at one layer you have twitter. That's hard to unit test, but can still be tested as a black box. The final user output layer is also difficult to test, and usually has to be manually confirmed. Every layer in between should be unit tested in isolation. For example - the question provides an example output from twitter - excellent! Use that output and hard-code it into the application and see if everything works for that particular scenario. Modify the code so that you can either hard-code it, or use the real twitter response - that's your UT!

Comment: @Arafangion good points. The fact that it's a live service makes it hard to unit test but that sounds workable. Although in this case, it looks like the whole basic idea of what the script is supposed to do is botched